# Can I assume "Perf" is a commonly understood abbreviation for "Performance" in the context of Software Engineering?

Tags: performance, terminology

I have been using "Perf" when writing about performance of some pieces of software (in tools, pull requests, etc.) but was wondering recently if this was an appropriate practice.

Can I assume software engineers, both native and non-native English speakers, would understand what "Perf" means in this context?

(And just to make sure, there is no awkward connotation when using that abbreviation right?)

Comment: I would avoid all forms of abbreviations or other colloquialisms in text which is intended to be factual.   It's not about whether the audience understands what it means; casual language usage is disrespectful to the reader.    Reading a comment, commit, PR, readme, or other bit of factual text which sounds like somebody's twitter feed makes me doubt the competence of the author -- i.e. if they lack professionalism in the way they communicate information about their code, then that's a bad omen about their standards and professionalism in the way they'd written the code too.

Comment: "Perf test" and "Performance test" translate to the same output using Google's translator for as many languages as I tested, including Russian and Chinese. So it does seem likely it will be understood. Whether it is stylistically appropriate is a different question.

Comment: yes, its perf..ect

Comment: search replace?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Can I assume software engineers, both native and non-native English speakers, would understand what "Perf" means in this context?

I think the current (this millenium) consensus is that saving maybe three seconds while typing and 7 bytes in disc space is not worth making any assumption about your readers ability to decypher your writing. Just write the full word. Even a lifetime in savings of this sort would probably be dwarfed by just buying a 4.99 USB stick from Amazon.

Will the majority get it? Yes, very likely. But programming and communication is not democracy. We don't aim for a majority, we aim to reach everybody. Even yourself, two years down the road, at 5 in the morning on a Sunday with no coffee yet, trying to fix that damn production bug.

Make it easy for everyone, not just the average Joe in the average situation. Because lets face it: on average, we don't need those comments. We need them only when something bad happened.

Comment: If you spell Perl wrong, how am I supposed to guess that you meant Perf?

Comment: Perforation, Perfection, Perfume, perfidious, and we are not even at rare words like perfusion.

Comment: And don't forget that business domains have their own abbreviations, which can clash with abbreviations used in programming. You do not want a programmer with domain expertise getting "perf(ormance)" confused with a business-specific term, which might not be "performance". As a general rule, don't abbreviate.